# Maintenance Plan Reporting - Append To File - Clean Up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-administration, maintenance, database-backup

**Background:** (SQL Server 2005, Standard Ed.)  I have a maintenance plan running backups, taking a full backup 1/day, and t-log every 15 minutes.  I have it set to create a text file report of each run, but that creates A LOT of files on the file server.  These are hard to sort through, which makes them less useful.

**Question:**  There is an option in "Reporting and Logging" settings for appending all logs together, but how do you clean this out? If you're appending to the same log file every time, how should you make sure this file doesn't grow indefinitely?  Is there a build-in function to clean out portions of appended logs like there is for cleaning out individual old log files?

Answer (score 0):

Use the History Cleanup Task in your maintenance plan.

Comment: I thought that just cleaned out the database table that kept track of the database.  I have another task set that can find files by extension (e.g. trn) and delete them from a folder if they're X days old.  But can that look inside a file and delete backup data that is X days old?